# Use React Native to run js on android and ios?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, user-interface, react-native

how can i use ReactNative just for app logic and implement ui natively in android with java and ios with swift ?
it's mean use react native to run js on android and ios.

if you have another option to run js on android and ios, please give me.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org). It has everything your looking for.